# Why doesn't numpy.where give me the correct answer?

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

I'm trying to estimate the number of neutrons that passes through a "wall" without being reflected or absorbed for starters, but, `numpy.where` doesn't give me the right answer:

```
import numpy as np

Tabx = np.zeros(10)
Tabcos = np.ones(10)
actif = np.ones(10, dtype=bool)
iActif = np.where(actif)[0]
pa = 0
ps = 0

for i in range(15):
    iActif = np.where(actif)[0]
    r = np.random.random(10)
    l = -1 * 0.2 * np.log(r[iActif])
    Tabx[iActif] += l * Tabcos[iActif]

    if np.where(Tabx[iActif] > 1)[0].size!=0:
        actif[np.where(Tabx[iActif] > 1)[0]]=False

    print("itération: ", i + 1)
    print(Tabx)
    print(actif)
    print(iActif)
```

I'll show only when it starts to be wrong:

```
itération:  6
[ 1.34250751  1.22131969  0.61147827  0.72320522  1.18101783  0.2767469
  1.87170912  0.68726641  1.44933786  1.25179186]
[False False False False False False  True  True  True  True]
[3 6 7 8 9]
```

And the problem doesn't stop.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  It looks like `iActif` is one step behind `actif`.

Comment: Sometimes it is and sometimes not.

Comment: Do you know how to fix it?

Because, my problem is that it doesn't give me the right one, because they are not over 1. , so when I continue my code it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't part of your big problem, but this block can probably be simplified:

```
if np.where(Tabx[iActif] > 1)[0].size!=0:
    actif[np.where(Tabx[iActif] > 1)[0]]=False
```

to

```
actif[ Tabx[iActif]>1] = False
```

But you haven't made any attempt to describe what this is supposed to be doing, nor what exactly it is doing wrong.  I have no idea what 'right one' is.

Comment: Now that I read my question again, it is true that I mistold my problem. Sorry. The wrong thing is that the code should consider True when values of Tabx are over 1.

Comment: Sorry, it should consider False when values of Tabx are over 1.